# How to get the position of the mouse

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I am new to C++, directX and Windows programming.

I am programming a game using UWP, and I cannot find the position of the mouse, I have searched and all the solutions only work for windows desktop.

I would like to know how I can find the position of the mouse relative to the window.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know nothing about UWP. But I've still managed to search "uwp get mouse position c++/cx" and [read the top result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.pointerpoint). I wonder how you search.

Comment: the top result is in js

Comment: The 4th bar of the linked web page counting from the top let me choose language. I don't know whether your browser show that to you properly.

Comment: Answer perhaps depends on how you are handling input. Which you didn't show.

Comment: @NickyC: C++/CX is not C++. Although I'm sure the documentation will eventually get updated to include Standard C++, once C++/WinRT is incorporated into the Windows SDK.

Comment: Point pt =  args.GetCurrentPoint(scrollviewer()).Position();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A UWP application has access to the pointer position through the [CoreWindow::PointerPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corewindow#Windows_UI_Core_CoreWindow_PointerPosition) property. The property returns the position in client coordinates, i.e. relative to the window.

Comment: That returns the position of the mouse relative to the top left corner of the screen